# proper way to isolate code intended to be modified in the future?

Tags: java, collaboration

The class has constructors and variables and methods that should not be modified. Within the class is also a very large method that, one I pass along the project, will be modified and built upon and forked by others.
Is there a way to isolate code that will be modified into their own files, and what would be the most people way of doing that? Another class, an interface, or just keep it in the same file?

Comment: A very large method is normally a bad code smell, but without seeing the code, or knowing what it does, we can't really make any helpful suggestions.

Comment: Comment it out with `/*/`?

Comment: Just define an interface that will be implemented by the client, call the method through that interface.